# Why doesn't nmap return open port info when I fragment packets?

Tags: nmap, network-scanners, packet

I'm performing a scan on a remote host and playing around with the `-f` flag for `nmap` when I noticed something I hadn't expected. In amongst the other data, when I type `nmap -v -O <hostname>` I get a listing of open ports and OS details:

```
PORT    STATE   SERVICE
22/tcp  closed  ssh
80/tcp  open    http
443/tcp open    https
Device type: general purpose
Running: QEMU
OS CPE: cpe:/a:qemu:qemu
OS details: QEMU user mode network gateway
TCP Sequence Prediction: Difficulty=17 (Good luck!)
IP ID Sequence Generation: Incremental
```

However, when I scan the same how with `nmap -v -f -O <hostname>`, I get:

```
All 1000 scanned port on <host> <ip> are filtered
Too many fingerprints match this host to give specific OS details
```

Can anyone explain why fragmented packets act differently in regard to the information received? Is the remote host likely set up to block fragmented packets, maybe?

Comment: please read the nmap manual on the -f option

Comment: I'm getting `-f; --mtu <val>: fragment packets (optionally w/given MTU)`. But I guess you mean on their website?

Comment: yes, the manual, not the help text

Comment: Another case of RTFM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found this in the nmap documentation at: https://nmap.org/book/man-port-scanning-basics.html

> IP fragmentation is a complex system and implementations are riddled
>   with bugs and inconsistencies. Possible tests could examine how
>   overlapping fragments are assembled or time the defragmentation
>   timeouts. These tests are avoided for Nmap because many firewalls and
>   other inline devices defragment traffic at gateways. Thus Nmap may end
>   up fingerprinting the firewall rather than the true destination host.
>   In addition, fragments are difficult to send on some operating
>   systems. Linux 2.6 kernels have a tendency to queue the fragments you
>   are trying to send and assemble them itself before transmission.

So it seems that the process of fragmentation may be causing problems with the lookup. I would still appreciate any answers that explain this in more depth, though, if that is within the scope of the site.